# jquery function stops working after div refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one function that refreshes the div but the then the jquery function won't work any more. I've seen answers where I have to use the about it losing the bindings but I can't get it to work.

refresh div code working fine

```
 $(document).on('click', '#reload', function () {
    //Load next question
    $("#new_sen").load(" #new_sen");   
});
```

My code that won't work after div refresh

```
 $(".card_flip").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');

 })
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: maybe it's because you have an empty space in the load method: `load(" #...")` see how there's an empty space after the double quote after load. should be `load("#...")`

Comment: See "Delegated event handlers" in https://api.jquery.com/on/  You are destroying the event handler when you load new content. Either recreate the handler or use the example(s) in the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it throw an error or just not run? Try replacing:

```
$(".card_flip").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
})
```

with:

```
$(document).on('click', '.card_flip', function () 
    $('.card_flip').toggleClass('flipped');
})
```

If problem is a dynamic element not being handled, the former only applies to elements on the page when it's run. Latter should continue to handle any clicks for .card_flip elements added after page load.

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery still works, it just loses the reference to the element if you use `reload()`.

Try using `html()` on a container to load new questions:

```
 $("#new_sen").html('<div class="new_question">another question...</div>');
```